# listener ports restart resets message cursor

Tags: cursor, jms, listener, message, mq

IBM MQ JMS Listener environment.
MQ is priority based queue not FIFO.

Scenario: I am receiving all the messages of same priority. Messages received at 6.50AM and 9.30AM are sitting in the queue till evening lets say. Many messages which came in during the day are getting processed. I assume that this is a problem with message cursor. When a cursor is moved to NEXT position at 6.50AM and at the same time, a message is received, this message is not going to be processed until the cursor reaches the end of the queue and comes back to the first position. Is this statement right?

Next question, when the application is restarted, will it reset the message cursor to the first position?

Also when the listener ports are stopped for a while( 10 mins lets say) and started , will the cursor moves back to the first position?

Any pointers/replies are greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Abi

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the scenario properly. In any case: If all your messages have the same priority, then messages will be delivered in FIFO. Effectively your listener should receive all messages, no messages should sit in queue till evening.

You can also change the MSGDLVSQ to FIFO if your messages have the same priority. In `runmqsc` do a `alter ql(WCFQ) MSGDLVSQ(FIFO)` to change.

When application is restarted, the message at the top of the queue would be received unless if you have set some message selectors. Same is the case when port is restarted.